# docker0 boot2docker network changing between restarts

Tags: linux, networking, mac-osx, docker

I'm experiencing an issue where after restarting my `boot2docker` VM the `docker0` network segment changes between 172.17.0.0/16 to 172.18.0.0/16

That is a problem since I have a DNS container running with a static IP as the `docker0` gateway, which is 172.17.42.1/172.18.42.1. So if the gateway changes everyt ime I restart my VM I'm forced to recreate the container with configured with the new gateway. Besides that I'm also adding a static route on my mac to access the `docker0` network as well as configuring my primary DNS to be the `docker0` gateway.

Is there a way to make `boot2docker` not change the `docker0` network segment on every restart?

More details:

The office docker docs states that a random range from the RFC 1918 is selected for the `docker0` subnet https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

After doing some testing I noticed that the range only changes after I change the primary DNS on my Mac, restart the interface and restart the VM

- Change primary DNS
- `sudo ifconfig en7 down && sudo ifconfig en7 up`
- `docker-machine restart default`